# Finding the sum of $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$, $\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}$, $\cos\frac{5π}{7}$ by first finding a polynomial with those roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

> Without using tables, find the value of $$\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{5\pi}{7}$$

This is a very common high school trigonometric problem, and the usual way to solve this is by repeated application of trigonometric identities. But I thought of a bit different approach.

> Somehow, if we can find a polynomial whose roots are the three terms of the above expression, then we can apply Vieta's formula to find the value.

So please help me with it. (Any hint will be appreciated.)

Comment: If complex numbers using is allowed, then it's easy to see that $2\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)+2\cos \left(\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)+2\cos \left(\frac{5\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{7\pi}{7}\right)=0$.

Comment: @Oleg567 Even if complex number are _not_ allowed, this is still probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: How are we getting  this?

Comment: @ami_ba: draw regular $7$gon $A_1 A_2 A_3...A_7$ with center at origin and one of the vertices at $(-1,0)$, then apply vector sum of $OA_1, OA_2, ..., OA_7$. Then $\cos(\pi/7)$, ... are projections of vertices $A_1, ..., A_7$.

Comment: The three cosines are the roots of the polynomial $8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$. Wolfram Alpha happened to spit it out when I was playing around with the cosines. Actually finding that polynomial by hand is probably much harder than any of the other methods for getting the sum.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis This is exactly what I want...is there really no way to find this by hand?

Comment: @ami_ba: The "brute force" method of finding the appropriate polynomial is to expand the expression $$\cos 7x +1$$ (which is zero for $x=$ "odd $\pi/7$") in terms of $\cos x$. After some tedious symbol-crunching, both expanding and factoring, we get $$\cos 7x + 1= (1+c) (1 - 4 c - 4c^2 + 8c^3)^2$$ where $c:=\cos x$. The first factor is extraneous for our values; and, since we're presumably looking for a minimal polynomial, we can ignore the square on the second factor. Thus, $$1 - 4 c - 4c^2 + 8c^3$$ is the polynomial you seek, so that, by Vieta's formula, $-(-4/8)=1/2$ is the target sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on finding a polynomial, you can do it via [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).
These polynomials are defined by $T_n(\cos \theta)=\cos n\theta$, and can be generated through the recurrence relation:

$$T_0(x)=1\\ T_1(x)=x \\ T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$$

By going through this recurrence you can find that $T_7(x)=64x^7-112x^5+56x^3-7x$.
So for the cosines in this problem we have $T_7(\cos (k\pi/7))= \cos k\pi = -1$. This means that the cosines are roots of $f(x)=T_7(x)+1$.
$$f(x)=64x^7-112x^5+56x^3-7x+1=(x+1)(8x^3-4x^2-4x+1)^2$$

It is no surprise they are double roots or that $-1$ is a root too. Because of this you could actually do this factorization by hand, by taking the greatest common polynomial divisor $f$ and its derivative $f'$: $$\gcd(f(x),f'(x)) = \\
\gcd(64x^7-112x^5+56x^3-7x+1,\ 448x^6-560x^4+168x^2-7) =\\ 8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$$
using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) with [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

In this way we can find the polynomial $8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$ which has exactly those three cosines as roots. Their sum is therefore $-\frac{-4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Great answer, by the way :)

Comment: Thank you, wonderful answer, today I learnt something new

Answer (score 3):

Using $$-1+2\sum_{n=1}^3\cos\frac{\pi n}{7}=\sum_{n=-3}^3\cos\frac{\pi n}{7}=\sum_{n=1}^7\cos\frac{\pi n}{7}=0,$$ we have $$\sum_{n\in\{1,\,3,\,5\}}\cos\frac{\pi n}{7}=\sum_{n=1}^3\cos\frac{\pi n}{7}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Using Complex Number}$

Let $z=e^{\frac{\pi i}{7}},$ so $z^7=-1.$ Let $Q$ be the desired quantity. Then
$$2Q=z+\frac{1}{z}+z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}+z^5+\frac{1}{z^5} = \frac{z^{10}+z^8+z^6+z^4+z^2+1}{z^5} = \frac{z^{12}-1}{z^5(z^2-1)}$$
$$=\frac{-z^5-1}{z^7-z^5} = \frac{-z^5-1}{-1-z^5} = 1$$ $$\therefore Q=\frac{1}{2}\ \ \square$$

Comment: How would you *think* to substitute such a value $z$? Brilliant! It is unfortunate that I reached my daily voting limit, like, only two minutes ago...

Answer (score 1):

Consider numbers: $$\omega_k=e^{i\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{7} }=\cos\left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{7}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi k}{7}\right), \qquad k=1,...,7.$$

Easy to see ([De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)) that $$w_k^7=e^{i(2k-1)\pi}=e^{i\pi}=-1, \qquad k=1,...,7.$$

So, all  $\omega_k$ are solutions of equation
$$
\omega^7-1 = 0.\tag{1}
$$
Denote unknown value $\omega$ as $\omega=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ (simply, $\omega = c+is$).
So:
$$
c^7 + i 7c^6s- 21 c^5s^2- i 35c^4s^3 + 35 c^3s^4 +i 21c^2s^5-7cs^6-is^7-1=0.
$$

Focusing on real part of the equation, we have
$$
c^7 - 21 c^5s^2 + 35 c^3s^4 -7cs^6+1=0.\tag{2}
$$
Now replace each $s^2$ with $(1-c^2)$:
$$
64c^7-112c^5+56c^3-7c+1=0.\tag{3}
$$
Knowing that $c=-1$ is one of solutions of equation $(3)$ and that $\cos\left(\dfrac{(2k-1)\pi}{7}\right)$ are double-solutions of eq. $(3)$ (I mean: $\cos \frac{\pi}{7}=\cos\frac{13\pi}{7}$, $\cos \frac{3\pi}{7}=\cos\frac{11\pi}{7}$, $\cos \frac{5\pi}{7}=\cos\frac{9\pi}{7}$), we can factor its LHS:
$$
\left(8c^3-4c^2-4c+1\right)^2(c+1)=0.
$$
Therefore, the equation for $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$, $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)$,$\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{7}\right)$ has form
$$
8c^3-4c^2-4c+1=0.
$$